AWS SageMaker Project template creation failing
I am trying to create a project using already provided template "Model building, training, and deployment" in AWS Sagemaker studio. However, I am encountering the following error: https://i.sstatic.net/e8MZgiMv.png
Following steps I did:

Create a domain in SageMaker.
domain

Added additional policies (AWSCodeCommitFullAccess, AmazonS3FullAccess, AWSCloudFormationFullAccess) to the IAM role attached with the domain.
iam


I still get that above error. Any clues as to what I am missing?
PS:
The quota of AWSCodeCommit is following:codecommitquota
Testing Code Commit Repo creation: codecommitrepo

check  your code commit quota in aws and let me know

I just added the status of quota on AWS Code Commit

ok one thing , can you try creating a codecommit repositroy in your account that you are using for this and let me know if you can or cant make it

I attached the status in the question. Is this what you meant me to do? I get a similar error while creating the repo as I get in my main question about no prior Repo available.

ok i got your issue as per our discussion in comment and your updated information , you are trying to create a project using already provided template "Model building, training, and deployment" in AWS Sagemaker studio and it  requires codecommit as one of the resource to be created to deploy this project.
But the bad news is Beginning on 06 June 2024, AWS CodeCommit ceased onboarding new customers. Going forward, only customers who have an existing repository in AWS CodeCommit will be able to create additional repositories.
link
Therfore i am sure your account is new after june 6, 2024 you are not able to create the project and facing the issue due to deprcation of codecommit service for new customers.
